# How to scale flask webapp build with Docker

Tags: json, docker, flask

We have a dockerized `flask` app which takes an image, process it and sends back the results in `JSON` format. The input image is sent using a `POST` request to the docker container.

Let's say we have huge traffic incoming then how can we scale this app. I'm new to docker, any advice would be of great help.

Comment: You need to search about how to scale docker app. Ever heard of kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `kubernetes` is a great solution for scaling `containerized` applications, I recommend also using `nginx` for load balancing. It is a proven solution, used by dozens of companies not only for routing and static file serving, but also for such tasks as balancing.

It should be used as a primary point for all incoming requests with subsequent routing them to back-end processing servers.

There is a dedicated help page on their site:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

Of course, it is also available as a `docker` image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kubernets for managing it for you.

If you use a cloud service such as aws, you can easily configure the number of images you have, the hours you want to have more machines running, etc.

It depends on what you use, or what you can use...